# Javascript: Show divs from another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was curious how i could make a div apear just inside one of this wrapp without making it apear on all the divs with the same class. I am using this divs as wrapper for something that will apear at least 5 or 6 times and i don`t want to display all the forms that are present on the page. I just want to show the one that i need to be displayed

Thanks in advance!

```
<div class="comment_wrap">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="user.png" wclassth="50" height="50" />
            </td>
            <td class="the_td">
                <h1><b>BMC</b> Says</h1>
                <br />
                <h2>Lorem ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</h2>
                <br />
                <h3><a href="#" title="Reply" onclick="show_reply()"> Reply</a></h3>
                <form method="post" class="create-reply">
                    <input type="text" class="author" name="author" placeholder="Enter your name" />
                    <br />
                    <textarea resize="no" name="limitedtextarea" class="comment" onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.limitedtextarea,this.form.countdown,255);" onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.limitedtextarea,this.form.countdown,255);"></textarea>
                    You have
                    <input readonly type="text" name="countdown" value="255" class="counter">characters left.
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reply!" class="post_reply" />
                </form>
            </td>

        </tr>

    </table>

</div>
```

To make things clearer. I have a lot of those divs on  one page. and  when I click that link on one div, i would like to make the form insclasse the div where the link is to show up. Hope i made it clear enough!

Comment: You should not have duplicate ids on a page! That is invalid HTML. Use classes or some other means of identifying the specific DIVs (unique ids would be best)

Comment: Don't use multiple divs with the same ID, use classes instead

Comment: Can you elaborate it, your question does not makes any sense to the community. Can you break down the situation you are at into simpler sentences / points, And ask the question at the end. All I can see now is  div, wrapper, same id  etc. but they don't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.comment_wrap').on('click', function() {
   var $div = $('<div>', {     
                text: 'So text, much jQuery'
            });

   $div.appendTo($(this)); 

});
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cr32T/)

Comment: yeah.. but this shows off all the forms inside all of the comment_wrap divs.

Comment: That's it, as it was pointed out: _do not have duplicate IDs_. The code works exactly how it should, your HTML does not conform to standards and hence it breaks the code. IDs are used to uniquely identify content, if you take that away, of course you can't do the think IDs are supposed to do, unless you make some more complex rule to determine uniqueness but it's not going to be (at least solely) based on ID.

Comment: changed to classes.. now.. can this be done? or not?

Comment: In the click even handler, just get a reference to `this` and use it - it'd be the element you've clicked on. Alternatively, find a unique way of identifying which div would be the target.